# Restricting Laravel Error Log by IP Address

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

When `debug` is set to `true` in Laravel's `app/config.php` is there any way to restrict the resultant `Whoops` error page with stack trace to certain IP addresses, and IPs not on that list being shown a specific view?

Thanks.

Comment: That sorta defeats the point of a lot of how Laravel debugs things. The point is to run debug mode in development, then turn it off before it hits beta/production.

Comment: They are two independant design decisions I would say, but thank you for sharing your view.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not built in no.

But you could probably implement this quite easily by capturing **all** exceptions and only re-throwing once you've compared the IP address of the user.

So in `app/start/global.php` you'd need to configure the "Application Error Handler". At the moment it captures all exceptions and simply logs them with `Log::error`. So in there you could compare the users IP address with an array of valid IP addresses:

```
App::error(function(Exception $exception, $code)
{
    Log::error($exception);

    $validIpAddresses = ['123.456.789.0', '321.654.987.0'];

    if (in_array(Request::getClientIp(), $validIpAddresses))
    {
        throw $exception;
    }

    return View::make('error');
});
```

Comment: Many thanks for the reply, this is approach I have adopted as I find it aesthetically more pleasing than the (equally valid) solution from Isemi.

I've tweaked it slightly to take the valid IP's from a file and likewise had to rewrite the `if` statement slightly as I found that Laravel reported an error when hitting the `throw` statement.

Comment: Ah yes you might have to reverse the statement. Rethrowing the exception would cause all kinds of problems.

Answer (score 2):

The `config.php` (or `app/config/app.php`) file is a PHP file like any other.

So nobody stops you from specifying

```
'debug' => in_array($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'], array('192.168.0.1','127.0.0.1')),
```

which will result in `debug` being `true` from some IP addresses, but not others.

**Update**: if running from the CLI, we may want

```
'debug' => array_key_exists('REMOTE_ADDR', $_SERVER)
        ? in_array($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'], array(
             '192.168.0.1',         /* List of allowed addresses */
             '127.0.0.1'
        ))
        : true /* Actually, whatever we want when going CLI */
        ;
```

You can even check for a "user password" embedded in the browser request (remember that it goes out in the clear unless you're using SSL; don't use "important" passwords).

```
'debug' => (strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], 'KLAATU-BARADA-NIKTO') > 0),
```

and then use, say, a [Firefox plug-in](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/user-agent-switcher/) to edit your browser's User-Agent and add a password. Then your browser will have the debug, but no other.

Comment: Thanks for that, so obvious I can only chalk it up to a "can't see the wood for the trees" moment!

Comment: `'debug' => in_array($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'], array('192.168.0.1','127.0.0.1')),` breaks the commands, php-cli does not have a remote address, so it throws a nasty error.

Comment: Thanks, attempted a fix.

Comment: @LSerni your ternay operator should be like: ```array_key_exists('REMOTE_ADDR', $_SERVER) ?   in_array($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'], [,,,]) : true```